# Yeoman Generator - Building Web Apps

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator

I have recently discovered Yeoman and it's great for the iterative process of building web apps. I am using the Angular-fullstack generator and when testing it works perfectly so far.

My question relates to how the "site" is build when executing "grunt build". This creates what I assume is intended to be a deployable version of the web app for a node express server.
The folder structure is as shown, the entry "html" file is in \dist\views. I would have expected in to be in the root folder.

[image]

Is it possible to build the webapp so it can be deployed on a more traditional server (i.e. Apache or IIS)?

Comment: Perhaps there is a front-end only generator for an angular webapp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "deploy on a more traditional server." You can get Node.js running on apache by looking [here](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache).

But do you mean on a server that just serves html and javascript, with no back end code? In that case use the [Angular Generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). It creates a front-end only web app; just run grunt build and drop the contents of the dist folder straight where you want it served from.